# C# Drawling lines in Forms App go of the screen

Tags: c#, forms

I'm learning how to draw things on screen using Forms Application. I want to make a Snake Game using grid.

I can currently draw a grid using this code. Problem is that my squares are drawn a bit of the screen. Once on the right of the screen are not a full box. I would also like so the lines of the edge are visible to the eye and not hidden like the bottom on in the picture.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    var numCells = (float)this.Height;
    var cellSize = 20.0F;

    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCells; i++)
    {
        //Vertical Lines
        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, i * cellSize, 0, i * cellSize, numCells * cellSize);

        //Horizontal Lines
        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, i * cellSize, numCells * cellSize, i * cellSize);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `var numCells = (float)this.Height;` Rethink if you really want that many cells.

Comment: OH yes right shoot I do not want 600 cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
var cellSize = 20.0F;
var numCells = Math.Floor((float)this.Height / cellSize);
```

since right now you're drawing lines waaaay off the screen too.

Comment: I got the same outcome.

Comment: Might be off by one, then - try subtracting 1 from that `numCells`.

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Is there a possibility to change the size of the cells for they fit the entire screen? As -1 makes a visible ending line but no actual side line just blank and it's about 10 pixels away from the right border.

Comment: Draw a rectangle around your whole grid, then...